# Correlación temporal en las oraciones con "cuando"

Tags: sintaxis

Un libro de gramática española dice:

> Precisamente esta significación de simultaneidad provoca que entre el
>   verbo principal y el de la subordinada adverbial haya una relación de
>   correlación temporal. El presente en el verbo principal exige la forma
>   presente en el subordinado; la forma de pretérito en el verbo
>   principal exige el pretérito en el subordinado.

Os doy dos ejemplos:

> (a) Me **sonrojo** cuando me **miras**.
>
> (b) Me **sonrojé** cuando me **miró**.

Encontré otro ejemplo en que el verbo de la principal va en pretérito mientras el de la subordinada va en presente:

> Cuando tu **vas** yo ya **fui**, **vine** y **regresé**.

Ahora me pregunto si este ejemplo es el único ejemplo (porque es un dicho) o tengo que poner en duda la regla de arriba? ¿Se os ocurre algún otro ejemplo similar con dos diferentes tiempos verbales?

Gracias.

Comment: Sospecho que el libro que has consultado indica algún caso más en que se usa *cuando* para introducir subordinadas: el que no indica simultaneidad, sino una acción terminada en el momento en que se desarrolla la otra. Es así en el ejemplo que nos presentas y en otros, como este caso con presente (de subjuntivo) y futuro: *cuando llegues al cine ya habrá terminado la película*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En ese ejemplo los verbos pueden tener tiempos diferentes porque las acciones a las que se hace referencia no son simultáneas. En los primeros ejemplos sí lo son: la persona se sonroja en el mismo momento en el que la otra lo mira. Sin embargo, en el segundo ejemplo no: cuando una persona hace una cosa (ir), la otra ya ha hecho otra (regresar).

Otro ejemplo:

> Cuando vosotros dormís, yo ya me he despertado.

Comment: ah sí claro, se trata de la simultaneidad... muchas gracias